# DynamoDB QuerySpec - not recognizing the schema type

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, schema, dynamodb-queries

I am attempting to use this code to query a table where the table has a partition key that is passed in as a primitive long and is set in **DDB** as a Number (in this case `idNumber` is being passed in as a String so I'm converting it to a long):

```
    long queryId = Long.parseLong(idNumber);
    dynamoDBQuery = new QuerySpec()
            .withKeyConditionExpression(idType + " = :v_id")
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                    .withLong(":v_id", queryId));
```

However, I am getting this error:

> "class": "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException",
> "message": "One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 9B9C943L42QUIHAVN2COS8D7F7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)"

I also tried the `.withNumber()` instead of `.withLong()` function - and I'm not having any luck so far. Let me know if someone can see if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I would suggest adding the logging which I have included below to confirm the datatype of the keys on your table, and the variable being passed in. There must be a mismatch.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build();

        DynamoDB ddb = new DynamoDB(client);
        
        final String TABLE_NAME = "Cust5";
        
        // Check keys data types of table
        System.out.println(client.describeTable(TABLE_NAME).getTable().getAttributeDefinitions());

        Table table = ddb.getTable(TABLE_NAME);

        long queryId = Long.parseLong("12345");

        // Check data type of query variable
        String x = ((Object) queryId).getClass().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println(x);

        QuerySpec dynamoDBQuery = new QuerySpec()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("pk" + " = :v_id")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                        .withLong(":v_id", queryId));

        // Get Items
        ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(dynamoDBQuery);

        // Log results
        Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
        Item item = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            item = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(item.toJSONPretty());
        }
    }
```